# In stellar frame dragging what is the 'frame'?

Tags: spacetime, supernova, frame-dragging

If a star rotation causes a frame rotation then there is an interaction between the two. Is it possible for the star to briefly expel this same frame away from its center when the star becomes a supernova?

Comment: As long as the star rotates frame-dragging is present. They are interconnected. Why should the star stop rotating when it becomes a (spherical symmetric) supernova?

Comment: I didn't say the star stops rotating. If it can move the frame making it rotate could it move it away like a cloud while exploding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame is the 4d frame around the non-rotating star (giving rise to gravity) which gets distorted in the case the star is rotating.

The picture below show the 2d space part of this dragged frame.

[image]